# Repeating a function in Python

Tags: python, function, repeat

How do I repeat a function in python. Such as Repeat... Unil in other languages. Thanks, this is the code I'm trying to repeat:

```
import random


line = random.choice(keywords)
print('Keyword:')
print (line)

line = random.choice(definitions)
print ('A:')
print (line)

line = random.choice(definitions)
print ('B:')
print(line)

line = random.choice(definitions)
print ('C:')
print(line)

#randomly selects a keyword and definition from the file

A = []
ans = input('Is it A, B or C?')
print()

if ans == 'A' :
    print ('Correct')
else:
    print ('Incorrect')

#asks the user for an answer, then tells them if their correct or not
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how many times? why didn't you google?

Comment: Python supports 'for' and 'while'

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop for infinity (or until a certain condition is met):

```
while True:
    # Insert code here
    if conditition_to_break:
        break
```

This will call your code in an endless loop until `condition_to_break` is `True` and then breaks out of the loop.

You can read more on `while` loops [here.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

If you want to repeat something `n` times try using a `for` loop (read more [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)).

```
for x in range(3):
    # This code will execute 3 times
    print("Executed {0} times".format(x+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like `while` or `for`?
If you meant `do while` then it's a bit tricky in python, since python does not 
have a built-in function for it, but your can do this:

```
while(True):
   your_code_here()
   if(your_exit_term): break
```

I know it's ugly, but I'm not familiar with any other way.